# No Search results after query when using Q Expression in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following class based view which I have Implemented a custom query functionality but when I try to search I am not getting the results. I have the data available in the db for employee details but no results. o far this is how my Q filter looks like.

```
class PayslipSearch(ListAPIView):
# queryset = Payslip.obejcts.all()
serializer_class = PayslipDetailSerializer
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
search_fields = ['employee__user__first_name',
                 'employee__user__last_name',
                 'basic_salary__salary_value',
                 # 'payment_mode',
                 # 'payslip_no',
                 # 'month_ending',
                 # 'deductions',
                 # 'allowances'
                 ]

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset_list = Payslip.objects.all()
    # call GETs get to get your values
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    print(query)

    if query:
        queryset_list = Payslip.objects.filter(
            Q(employee__user__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(employee__user__last_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(basic_salary__salary_value__icontains=query)
            # Q(payment_mode__icontains=query) |
            # Q(payslip_no__icontains=query) |
            # Q(month_ending__icontains=query) |
            # Q(allowances__icontains=query) |
            # Q(deductions__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

    return queryset_list
```

Comment: Seems right to me should work, may be data is missing, may be params are missing. Please show serializer (though I don't see real need)

Answer (score 0):

How I have implemented the search:

```
class EmployeeSearch(APIView):

    # custom dictionary

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = self.request.query_params["q"]

        if query:
            queryset_list = Employee.objects.filter(
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query)
            ).values(
                'user__id', 'department', 'hr_number', 'salaries__salary_value',
                'tax_id_number', 'job_group', 'job_group_id',
                'identification_number',
                'joining_date', 'payslips',
                'user__last_name', 'user__first_name', 'user__email'
            )

        return Response(data=queryset_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```